# Magento 1 -> 2 Migration: do I "just" need a DB copy or the full code for the magento migration tool?

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool

we will use the default Magento migration script/tool supplied for migration from M1 to M2.

**Question**: do I "just" need a DB copy or the full code for the migration scripts to work?

Ie do I need a full production clone. Or is a Mysql copy enough? (for the data of course, images is logical data on disk - if so set in config)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only your database is enough to perform the data migration unless you plan for code migration. Navigate to your `data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/Magento_1_version/`. Rename `config.xml.dist` to `config.xml`. Configure the migration steps you want to be done by commenting out those un-needed.

You can configure the source and destination database name and access credentials here.

```
<source>
        <database host="localhost" name="magento1" user="root" />
</source>
<destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="magento2" user="root" />
</destination>
```

Please follow Magento documentation for detailed information https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html